# Joyal-Tierney definition of locally isomorphic objects

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I am struggling with Joyal-Tierney's paper *Strong stacks and classifying spaces*, (appeared in "Category Theory (Como, 1990)", volume 1488 of LNM, pp. 213–236, Springer 1991).

In particular one of the first sentences is totally out of my understanding:

> Torsors solve the problem of finding all objects $T$ locally isomorphic to a given object $S$ of [a topos] $\mathcal E$. Recall that $T$ is locally isomorphic to $S$ iff there exists a covering $K$ (meaning $K$ is nonempty) and an isomorphism $K\times T\to K\times S$ over $K$. Equivalently, $T$ is locally isomorphic to $S$ iff $Iso(S,T)\neq\emptyset$.

So, it seems that $S,T$ are locally isomorphic iff... they *are* isomorphic! This obviously can't be, but I'm not able to interpret in any different way the notation "$Iso(S,T)$". Even the definition of covering is kind of smoky: I've always seen a covering defined as a collection of arrows $\{K_i\to T\}_{i\in I}$ such that $\amalg_{i\in I}K_i=K\to T$ is epi, hence I would rather say that $T$ is locally isomorphic to $S$ iff there exists a covering $\{K_i\}$ such that $K_i\times T\cong K_i\times S$ as objects in $\mathcal E/K_i$.

Answer (score 5):

1) If $K_i \times T \cong K_i \times S$ for all $i$, then $\sqcup_i K_i \times T \cong \sqcup_i K_i \times T$.

2) $\mathrm{Iso}(S,T) \neq \emptyset$ does not mean that this sheaf has a global section. It means that there is an open covering on which there are sections.

Comment: While we're straightening out the terminology, "$K$ is nonempty" (in a parenthetical piece of the quote) doesn't mean simply that $K\neq\varnothing$ (or $K\not\cong\varnothing$) but rather that "$(\exists x:K)\,\text{true}$" has truth value $1$ in the internal logic of the topos.